# Mac App Store updates keep repeating; won't clear

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

My Mac App Store updates keep repeating. They won't clear. The update is clearly installed. I know this because the new features in the changelogs are visible in my apps when I open them. The update process itself also works smoothly; meaning the progress bar gradually fills for each item in the update list and displays no errors. The badges will clear, but whenever I go and click on Updates again the badges and all previous updates return. It's very annoying. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LMAO, I **finally** figured out the problem! I had completely reinstalled Snow Leopard from scratch and used SuperDuper to make a backup clone of my hard drive beforehand (which I had always been doing for backup). Then before putting anything else on, I had visited the Mac App Store to reinstall some software when I noticed it said I had all my apps already installed. It didn't take long to figure out that the Mac App Store reads any cloned hard drives you have attached and interprets them as installed apps as well. This would certainly explain why it thought I still had the older versions still installed. Huge bug.

Comment: Wow. That seems like some funky behavior.

Comment: The fact that Mac apps can run from any location means that it's still installed if it's mounted anywhere. TimeMachine does hide the "previous" versions from the store, but I can see how a manual copy would confuse the app store since it truly is still runnable from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app from the AppStore.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work and I have quite a few by now. I hope that doesn't become necessary. In case you didn't know it's happening to ALL apps. I have noticed though it SEEMS as though when an app gets an ADDITIONAL update for an app that has already pushed out an update, it straightens everything out for apps that are actually up to date. But it starts all over again. It's hard to explain, but it has happened a few times and have noticed the pattern.

Comment: I only suggest this because I had a VERY similar issue with my iPhone and as a result I had to uninstall and reinstall ever app, there was about 30. Took me a while but all was well afterwards.