# Can ghost app updates be cleared in OS X?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

I have this Twitter application that shows on my Mountain Lion available updates list but I don't have any twitter app on my Mac. I had, but I have deleted it times ago.

Since then, every time twitter updates their app, I receive a notification that a new update is available.

How do I get rid of this ghost app update entry that haunts updates list in the App Store app?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [rebuilding the Launch Services database](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/how-can-i-reinstall-an-application-that-the-mac-app-store-thinks-is-installed-al?lq=1)?

Comment: just did. It is still there...

Answer (score 2):

In almost all cases, this is one of two things:

- somewhere on your Mac, an older copy of the App is [lying around and in need of an update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/mac-app-store-updates-keep-repeating-wont-clear) (even though the version in /Applications is up to date)
- spotlight is messed up

The first is much easier to fix, so eject all disks and network volumes and then quit and re-launch the App Store. If you still show an update, check for other copies of that app using spotlight.

Once you are sure it's not a case of more than one app, you can go down the more complicated path of spotlight triage/repair. I like to add all drives to spotlight’s privacy pane and delete all copies of the problem app and reboot. Then turn on spotlight for just the boot volume.

Once spotlight is done indexing that drive, go reinstall the problem app. If things are clear, enable spotlight on all remaining volumes. If not, we can cover that bigger spotlight issue in a different thread.

Comment: 1) unfortunately when I try to install the app, so I can remove it after that, I see an error: "unknown error" and the app is not download. All other apps can be installed, just twitter appears to be crapped. 2) there's no copy of this app on the computer or in any external disk. 3) I have rebuilt the index. 4) app continues to arrogantly sitting there...

Comment: Odd - what does the text on the right hand of the app store look like (or upload a wider shot of that window) for the status of the app on your system.

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem with 6 apps (including some of Apple's), and ejecting my attached bootable backup drive (then closing/re-opening the Mac App Store) got rid of the extra "Updates Available" list items.  Thanks!